# VS2015 preview + TypeScript 1.3 = error

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have just installed VS2015 Preview. I created a MVC project. I added a new typescript file. I have tried to compile and I got:

> The "TypeScript.Tasks.VsTsc" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\TypeScript.tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\TypeScript.tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.   WebApplication1

I have tried to search for `TypeScript.tasks.dll` and I only found:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\TypeScript.Tasks.dll

and

> c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\TypeScript\TypeScript.Tasks.dll

How to make it work?

Comment: Do you remember which options you selected when installing VS.

Comment: Looks like you had previous versions of VS (2012 and 2013?) installed on the same box, both with TypeScript configured. Can you confirm that.

Comment: I can see remainders of VS2010, VS2012 and fully working VS 2013. As long as I remember I chose to install Web development and Apache when installing VS2015. I also tried TypeScript in VS2013 after installing VS2015 and I got error that typescript exe is missing. I then installed TypeScript for VS2013 which installed all the missing files.

Comment: I want to add that if you are getting a similar error from JetBrain's Rider IDE, you can navigate to 

c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\vXX.X\

and copy all the missing folders to your MSBuild Jetbrains appdata folder ..\AppData\Local\Temp\JetBrains\MsBuildTools\vXX.X

This will resolve the missing dll issue for Rider.

Answer (score 9):

It helped to install TypeScript 1.3 for Visual Studio 2013 after the installation of the Visual Studio 2015. Strange...

Comment: I had the same problem. Running repair on the TS plugin for VS 2013 solved the problem.

Comment: I repair twice, first time it failed, but second time it success. And the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

There indeed seems something wrong with the installer for the TypeScript 1.3 powertool, I found that using the repair option in Add/Remove Programs fixed the install in most cases.